# HTML read metadata from file

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP based website and I want to make the code generic by reading the 'keywords' and 'description' metadata from a site specific include file ('META.TXT' say).

I have looked at the < link...> tag but I can't see how to use it to just include text.

I know how to read html content in using Javascript but I don't think that would work for header data.

```
<header>
<?php 
include_once("meta.php");
?>
</header>
```

I also tried:

```
<header>
<link rel="???" type="text/css" href="META.TXT">
</header>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Edited to show what little code there is.

Comment: Do you have a file called meta.php, as referred to in your first attempt shown, or was the extension a typo?

Comment: I do have a PHP version. It just contains two echo statements that echo the <meta name='... lines.  It didn't work. I suspect the timing is wrong doing it that way.

Comment: So basically you just need to include some HTML meta tags? Your first example should do that fine. You can also use `include`, `require`, etc. on non-PHP files.

Comment: Make sure in your `include_once` that you use the correct file path. You can temporarily change it to `require_once` to force a helpful error message if it can't find the file.

Comment: @faintsignal Too easy. Thank you. I was assuming I could only include PHP code. Make this an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea with your first example. `include_once` (as well as `include`, `require`, `require_once`) can be used to non-PHP files as well. Basically, any portion of your included file's content that is not wrapped in PHP tags (`<?php` `?>`) will be sent to output.

So if your meta tags are in a file called META.TXT (in the same or an accessible path) then they can be included in your header as follows:

```
<header>
<?php 
include_once("META.TXT");
?>
</header>
```

BTW, if your meta.php file had equivalent `echo` statements in it, that should have worked as in your first example also. Perhaps you forgot the `<?php` tag in that file.

Comment: You're right, I didn't have <?php in the include file because I was mistakenly thinking it was already inside the <?php from the higher level file. Thanks again!